# Flutter map.addAll() results in failure

Tags: dart, flutter

I got the following `List<Map>` in Flutter:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> recipeList = [
  {
'name': 'rec1',
'id': 1,
'img': 'images/recipe.jpg',
'ingredients': [{
  'name': 'salt',
  'amount': '1',
  'unit': '1',
},
{
  'name': 'flour',
  'amount': '100',
  'unit': 'g',
},
{
  'name': 'water',
  'amount': '100',
  'unit': 'g',
},
{
  'name': 'milk',
  'amount': '100',
  'unit': 'g',
},],
},]
```

I pass it down through several `Widgets` and at some point I want to add the key value pair `{'didBuy':false}` to every `Map` inside the ingredients list (which is basically `recipeList['ingredients']`). 
Thus I call:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> resultList = recipeList['ingredients'].map((elem) {
  elem.addAll({'didBuy': false});
  print(elem);
}).toList();
```

Unfortunately the following error message results: `Dart Error: Unhandled exception:type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, bool>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' of 'other'`.

Does anybody know what is the correct way to add something to a map, without getting this error message?

Edited the question to be more precise.

EDIT2:
After calling the type of the  `List` explicitly inside the `Map` as Hadrien suggested, I can add the key value pair with the boolean. Long term I want to fetch the data from the Internet, so I defined a RecipeObj:

```
class RecipeObj{

  String name;
  int id;
  String img;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> ingredients;

  RecipeObj(this.name, this.id, this.img, this.ingredients);

}
```

Here I explicitly state the type of the ingredients attribute, so I thought I could get of the explicit calling inside the (main) recipeList. But after passing the ingredients attribute down through some widgets, flutter recognizes it as `List<Map<String, String>>`, although I define it everywhere as an `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, why is that?

Comment: What is `ingredients` and `recipeList` are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: This code `recipeList['ingredients'].` is invalid. `recipeList` is a List, not a map and you need to access elements using an integer index. Perhaps you meant ``recipeList[0]['ingredients'].``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dart infer the type of your ingredients list with `Map<String, String>`

you can specify the type by yourself inside your list

```
'ingredients': <Map<String, dynamic>>[ {
  'name': 'salt',
  'amount': '1',
  'unit': '1',
 },
```

or build a new `Map<String, dynamic>` inside your `map` function

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> resultList = recipeList['ingredients'].map((elem) {
  final map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(elem);
  map.addAll({'didBuy': false});
  return map;
 }).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks, specify the type of the `List` inside the `Map` did the trick. But since this recipeList is just dummy data and finally will be fetched from the internet, I'm not quite happy with this approach. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: did you try the second approach ?

Comment: note that once you will get data from network, you will probably don't have this error anymore, `jsonDecode` should produce `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: Did work, thanks! I also noted, that when you have mixed value types like `String` and  `int` in the same map, flutter  recognizes it always as `Map<String, dynamic>` so there is no problem to add a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> recipeList = [
```

at least if `recipeList` and `ingredients` point at the same collection instance.

```
var ingredients = recipeList;
```

Comment: Thanks, it kinda helped me and I added it to my code, I also updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
void main() {

List<Map> recipeList = [
  {
'name': 'rec1',
'id': 1,
'img': 'images/recipe.jpg',
'ingredients': [{
  'name': 'salt',
  'amount': '1',
  'unit': '1',
},
{
  'name': 'flour',
  'amount': '100',
  'unit': 'g',
},
{
  'name': 'water',
  'amount': '100',
  'unit': 'g',
},
{
  'name': 'milk',
  'amount': '100',
  'unit': 'g',
},]
},];

  print("[DATA BEFORE ANY CHANGE]");
  print("recipeList.length=${recipeList.length}");
  print("recipeList[0][\"ingredients\"]=${recipeList[0]["ingredients"]}");
  print("recipeList[0][\"ingredients\"].last=${recipeList[0]["ingredients"].last}"); 
  print("recipeList[0][\"ingredients\"].length=${recipeList[0]["ingredients"].length}");

  // no recipe is worth if it doesn't contain chocolate
  recipeList[0]["ingredients"].add({
    'name': 'cocoa powder',
    'amount': '200',
    'unit': 'g',    
  });

  print("\n\n[DATA AFTER ADD]");
  print("recipeList[0][\"ingredients\"].last=${recipeList[0]["ingredients"].last}");
  print("recipeList[0][\"ingredients\"].length=${recipeList[0]["ingredients"].length}");
}
```

OUTPUT

```
[DATA BEFORE ANY CHANGE]
recipeList.length=1
recipeList[0]["ingredients"]=[{name: salt, amount: 1, unit: 1}, {name: flour, amount: 100, unit: g}, {name: water, amount: 100, unit: g}, {name: milk, amount: 100, unit: g}]
recipeList[0]["ingredients"].last={name: milk, amount: 100, unit: g}
recipeList[0]["ingredients"].length=4


[DATA AFTER ADD]
recipeList[0]["ingredients"].last={name: cocoa powder, amount: 200, unit: g}
recipeList[0]["ingredients"].length=5
```